# Auto increment Vertex property in orientdb

Tags: orientdb, graph-databases, orientdb-2.1, orientdb2.2

I am using **Orientdb 2.2.12**.

I want to set an auto-increment property to vertex

e.g

```
for(i 1 to 100)
{
  vertex.setProperty("counter", AUTO_INCREMENT_Value(start = 0))
}
```

I tried to achieve this by creating sequence

```
sequenceLibrary.createSequence(AUTO_INCREMENT_Value, SEQUENCE_TYPE.ORDERED, new OSequence.CreateParams().setStart((long) 0));

   for(int i=1 ; i<=100; i++)
       {
          vertex.setProperty("counter", AUTO_INCREMENT_Value);
          graph.commit();
          graph.shutdown();
       }
```

Though it work fine in single threaded system but **in multithreaded system it gave ambiguous results**.

I gave each thread a seperate OrientGraph instance from OrientGraphfactory as stated in official doc :

```
 OrientGraphFactory graphFactory = new OrientGraphFactory(
                        "remote:" +  IP + ":" + PORT+ "/" + appName).setPool(1, 100);
 OrientGraph graph = graphFactory.getTx();
```

Is there any way to achieve this in orientdb.

Thanks..!

Comment: Hi, what do you mean with ambiguous results?

Comment: value of  AUTO_INCREMENT_Value = [82, 96, ...] varied from time to time at the end of execution of program

Comment: This problem should be fixed here: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/6842